# Python Path.rglob failing on network error when encountering folder without permission

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I am new to Python and have been using this site as a reference...thanks for everything, I have learned a ton.  First question:

I am running a basic recursive file search with Path.rglob().  I am running into a error when it encounters a folder that it does not have permission to access.  I am running Python 3.7 on Windows and connecting to a windows share on a network drive.

Here's my code:

```
scan_folder = pathlib.Path("//192.168.1.242/Media")
nfo_files = list(scan_folder.rglob("*.nfo"))
```

It works perfectly until I encounter a folder that I do not have permission to access, then it errors out with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Working/media_tools/media_tools/movies_nfo_cataloger.py", line 337, in <module>
    nfo_files = list(scan_folder.rglob("*.nfo"))
  File "C:\Users\ulrick65\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 1094, in rglob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "C:\Users\ulrick65\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 544, in _select_from
    for p in successor_select(starting_point, is_dir, exists, scandir):
  File "C:\Users\ulrick65\Anaconda3\lib\pathlib.py", line 507, in _select_from
    entries = list(scandir(parent_path))
OSError: [WinError 59] An unexpected network error occurred: '\\\\192.168.1.242\\Media\\#recycle'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I searched and found the following Issue for Pathlib that appears to have been fixed, however the error is different in my case as it points to "Unexpected network error" instead of permissions.

https://bugs.python.org/issue24120

I verified that this is indeed a permissions error, I do not have access to that Recycle folder as the user I am logged in as.  I edited the permissions for that folder and gave myself access and the code runs fine after that.

I know I could use oswalk as it ignores these...but I figured given the bug fix I linked to above, so should path.glob however it doesn't.  Also, using path.rglob() is pretty slick, one line of code and is fast (not that oswalk wouldn't be just as fast).

Any help is appreciated.